# OverlappingFileLockException in tomcat start-up

Tags: java, tomcat, hornetq

I'v added [custom jndi-resource factory](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding_Custom_Resource_Factories) to my tomcat (jndi-resource for ConnectionFactory of an embedded hornetq). My resource needs some config files; I put them in `${catalina_home}/hornetq` folder. I have a test-web-app that uses this resource in tomcat start-up. In tomcat start-up, When test-web-app wants to use my resource, the resource wants to lock config files but it can't, and it throws `OverlappingFileLockException:

```
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1056)
    at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.tryLock(FileLockNodeManager.java:266)
    at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.isBackupLive(FileLockNodeManager.java:82)
    at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl$SharedStoreLiveActivation.run(HornetQServerImpl.java:2161)
    at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.start(HornetQServerImpl.java:450)
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.start(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:485)
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.embedded.EmbeddedJMS.start(EmbeddedJMS.java:115)
    at ...
```

Is it possible to disable file locking (files in `${catalina_home}/hornetq` directory) in tomcat or OS?

**Update:**

My jndi-resource in `context.xml` file in tomcat (A connection factory with name: `/ConnectionFactory` is defined in `hornetq-jms.xml`):

```
<Resource name="jms/ConnectionFactory" auth="Container" 
    type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"
    factory="com.wise.jms.hornetq.embedded.HornetqConnectionFactoryBuilder"
    cf-name="/ConnectionFactory" singletone="true"/>
```

My factory class: `HornetqConnectionFactoryBuilder`. I put the jar containing this class in `${catalina_home}/lib` directory (The embedded hornetq will be started in the first `getObjectInstance` method call):

```
public class HornetqConnectionFactoryBuilder implements ObjectFactory{

    private EmbeddedJMS embeddedJMS;
    private static final String ConnectionFactoryName = "cf-name";
    private static final String HornetqConfigDirectoryPath = getCatalinaHomePath() + "/conf/hornetq/";
    private static final String JmsConfigFilePath = HornetqConfigDirectoryPath + "hornetq-jms.xml";
    private static final String HornetqConfigFilePath = HornetqConfigDirectoryPath + "hornetq-configuration.xml";

    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws Exception{
        Properties properties = initProperties((Reference) obj);
        validateProperties(properties);
        initHornetq();
        String connectionFactoryJndiName = (String) properties.get(ConnectionFactoryName);
        return embeddedJMS.lookup(connectionFactoryJndiName);
    }

    private synchronized void initHornetq() throws Exception{
        if (embeddedJMS == null){
            embeddedJMS = new EmbeddedJMS();
            embeddedJMS.setJmsConfigResourcePath(JmsConfigFilePath);
            embeddedJMS.setConfigResourcePath(HornetqConfigFilePath);
            embeddedJMS.start();
        }
    }

    private Properties initProperties(Reference reference) throws IOException{
        Enumeration<RefAddr> addresses = reference.getAll();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
            RefAddr address = addresses.nextElement();
            String type = address.getType();
            String value = (String) address.getContent();
            properties.put(type, value);
        }
        return properties;
    }

    private void validateProperties(Properties properties){
        validateSingleProperty(properties, ConnectionFactoryName);
    }

    private static String getCatalinaHomePath(){
        String catalinaHome = System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME");
        if (catalinaHome == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("CATALINA_HOME environment variable should be set");
        }
        return "file:///" + catalinaHome.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
    }

    private static void validateSingleProperty(Properties properties, String propertyName){
        if (!properties.containsKey(propertyName)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(propertyName + " property should be set.");
        }
    }
}
```

My test-web-app `Test` Class (test method will be lunch in test-web-app start-up):

```
public class Test{
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public Test() throws NamingException{
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) envCtx.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");
    }

    public void test() throws JMSException{
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(true,Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue("testQueue");
        MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
        MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        TextMessage message1 = session.createTextMessage("This is a text message1");
        messageProducer.send(message1);
        session.commit();
        TextMessage receivedMessage = (TextMessage) messageConsumer.receive(5000);
        session.commit();
        System.out.println("Message1 received after receive commit: " + receivedMessage.getText());
    }

    public void setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

**Note:** when i put (hornetq) config files in the jar class-path, i have no problem and everything is fine!! (tomcat: 6, hornetq: 2.4.0.Final, OS: windows 7)

Comment: The HornetQ didn't write the integration for Tomcat... so I'm not sure how you made the integration to Tomcat, So there will be something else missing in your integration.


I would suggest you produce a bit more information so we can help you. maybe you should start a HornetQ user's forum where we can do a bit more of a discussion style and see what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other deployments in the Tomcat?
There is very well chance that once you restart tomcat, some other project gets deployed first which uses the file in the lib folder.

Try deploying it in a fresh tomcat installation or remove other folders from the webapps folder in Tomcat.